# Write out a statement that gives exactly the same final result column (under the ?) as the following truth table:

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I don't know what the statement could be. I think it is something along the lines of $p \land(q \lor r)$.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ p \land ( q \implies r ) $$